# Calculate the week number of a given date using a given a reference year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, week-number

I have a formula which calculates the week number of a given date:

```
=WEEKNUM(Sheet2!N83)
```

I want a formula which returns the week number using 2018 as reference, in a similar manner as the above formula does. If the year is 2019, I want it to return weeknum + 52, so for 2019-01-01 I get week number '53'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only valid for years 2018 and 2019:

```
=IF(YEAR(Sheet2!N83)=2018,WEEKNUM(Sheet2!N83),WEEKNUM(Sheet2!N83)+52)
```

or:

```
=IF(YEAR(Sheet2!N83)=2018,WEEKNUM(Sheet2!N83),WEEKNUM(DATE(2018,MONTH(Sheet2!N83),DAY(Sheet2!N83)))+52)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need a formula which calculates the difference in weeks.

In `A1` cell, fill the first day of the reference year (e.g. `2018-01-01`).

In `A2` cell, put the day of the week of your interest (e.g. `2019-01-03`).

In the `A3` cell, use this formula to calculate the difference in weeks (in case your week begins at Mondays):

```
=ROUNDDOWN((DATEDIF(B1-WEEKDAY(B1-2), B2, "d") / 7), 0) + 1
```

Or this one (in case your week begins at Sundays):

```
=ROUNDDOWN((DATEDIF(B1-WEEKDAY(B1-1), B2, "d") / 7), 0) + 1
```